# Laravel snappy error code 1073741819 - Loading pages 1/6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-snappy

```
OS:Windows 10 pro

PHP: 7.3.5

Laravel: 5.8
```

I have installed below packages based on composer suggestion

```
  "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.4",
    "wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf": "1.1.*",
    "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.2.3"
```

binary path

```
'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
```

Showing error

```
"The exit status code '-1073741819' says something went wrong:↵stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
↵[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
↵QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
↵[========>                                                   ] 14%
[=============>                                              ] 23%
"↵stdout: ""↵command: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf" --lowquality "C:\Users\DELL~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy5d2ee6e73b39b3.84603457.html" "D:\work\www\myapp/public/job-cards/job-card-1-07-17-2019_0914am.pdf"."
trace: [{file: "D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\knplabs\knp-snappy\src\Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator.php",…},…]
```

UPDATE

```
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin>wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
QPainter::begin(): Returned false============================] 100%
Error: Unable to write to destination
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

command line also giving same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of presence of JS in google.com page, using only html content, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the github issues of the library used by Laravel snappy package? there are some similar issues reported there. As you did not mention enough details about the scenario in which you are facing the issues, if is hard to suggest a direct solution.

Please check the following issue and you may find the solution.

1. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1873
2. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1570
3. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1512